# Simple form layout with CSS

Tags: css, grid

I have this html code:

```
<form>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Label1</label>
    <input/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Longer label 2</label>
    <textarea>Some text</textarea>
  </div>

</form>
```

How can I display this in a nice grid without setting a fixed width for the labels and without changing the html code?

The result should look like this:

```
Label1           Input
Longer label 2   TextArea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS-Tables**

```css
.form-group {
  display: table-row;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 .5em .5em
}
```

```html
<form>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Label1</label>
    <input/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Longer label 2</label>
    <textarea>Some text</textarea>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is your best friend. Bootstrap grids are based on them too.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
<form style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div class="form-group">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  </div>
</form>
```

you can then style your form-group according to your needs like flex-grow flex-order...

Answer (score -2):

You should use bootstrap for this. It will be very helpful creating this kind of layout.

Comment: @r03 please don't downvote just because you didn't specify your question enough. The suggestion to use bootstrap is obvious but still a valid answer

Comment: Suggesting a framework is a **comment** not an answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D then why your ans is not stated as solutionm